# objshell.regwrite wont work

Tags: vbscript

It works with:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoFolderOptions", 1, "REG_DWORD"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

But it doesn't work with:

```
Set objShell = CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Policies\Explorer\NoDrives", 3FFFFFF, "REG_DWORD"
Set objShell = Nothing
```

For the second one it will have an end of statement error. Why is that?

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is [here](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/931626) (read the whole page, there is also vbs example code).

**Note** that only decimal values can be added as strings (as described in the article).

Comment: Writing a string as a DWORD value as described in the KB article does not work with hexadecimal values.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers - Yes, not tested by me, am too in doubt for this KB article. Maybe is good to keep my answer as reference? or to delete it?

Comment: The answer isn't wrong, otherwise I would've downvoted it. You could add a note, though, that only decimal values can be added as strings (as described in the article).

Answer (score 0):

You get the error because `3FFFFF` is neither a valid variable name nor valid notation for a hexadecimal number. Try this:

```
objShell.RegWrite "HKCU\...\NoDrives", &h3FFFFFF, "REG_DWORD"
```